# Acrobat Pro XI does not start up

Tags: adobe-acrobat

When I run Adobe Acrobat XI pro, it won't start.
Nothing happens as if I did nothing.
Even I uninstalled and installed again, it's the same.
What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try a reboot?

Comment: Try closing other programs you have running even programs you have running in the tray.  Try launching it after that and if it works one of your other programs is hosing it.  I've had this happen to my with other programs that hook into other applications such as GreenShot (screen capture utility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Acrobat Cleaner tool](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html) for uninstall. Install the last version.

> The Adobe Reader and Acrobat Cleaner Tool removes a standalone
>   installation of Reader or Acrobat, including any preferences and
>   settings that may be preserved during a standard program uninstall.
>   The tool has both a user interface as well as a command line
>   interface.

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me:

Open acrobat distiller-->press accept on the 'license agreement'-->launch acrobat pro XI (which should be opened properly now).

Comment: didn't work for me, distiller seems to quit as well

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Simply ensure Adobe Acrobat shortcut is not running in compatibility mode. As soon as I unchecked this option, walla!! The application opened like a boss! I'm running Windows 8.1